# One PHP app that looks different when access from different domains

Tags: php, url, content-management-system

I'm working for a small web design firm and we are looking to implement a home brewed CMS to help manage our sites.

Currently we install our CMS in a separate folder under a unique user for each customer, then point their domain at that folder.

The difficult part with this is backporting important changes, for instance that async new google analytics code, or our improved way of preventing comment spam.

A couple of questions about a better way:

1: is it advisable to use the same backend code for every site we produce?

2: Assuming yes, what's the best way? I'd though of checking $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] to determine which template, database connection etc to use.

Anyone any previous experience of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're all hosted on the same physical server, you'd want `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, which is the domain the user is requesting. `SERVER_NAME` is the physical name of the server itself (which is set by Apache's `ServerName` directive).

There's no problem hosting multiple sites off the same code base, if they're not too different from each other. If it's just a matter of some branding and changing bit of text/graphcis here and there, no biggie. But if you're doing fundamentally different sites, then your code will become an unmaintainable mess of "if servername is X then do this else do something else".

Comment: Ha, of course it's http host, just been writing loads of code dealing with server name and my brain must have still been there!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it that way, having one main CMS that pushed out multiple sites, and moved away from it before it went live. The problems we had were with updates and changes. Any kind of customization is right out the window without a lot of extra work. Want to add a form field? Get ready for heartache. In the end we did what you have now, multiple installs, but with a few major scripts the they all shared in which the calling scripts passed which site was requesting what, such as the form mailer and security checks.

For mass updates that we knew would be the same across all of them, or across multiple pages we'd either write an update script that'd search and replace in the files, or do it in BBedit.

With something like google analytics I have a feeling you'd be forced to make those changes manually anyway since they would all have unique ID's.